# Excel Worksheet Dimensions throws namespace error at compilation. Namespace name could not be found

Tags: c#

I've inherited a large ASP .NET project and I'm having trouble compiling it, even though the code works fine (allegedly) from the international developers.

I've tried to change the class name ExcelWorksheet to ExcelWorksheet Dimension. I've also tried generating a new class called ExcelWorksheet

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;


namespace OfficeOpenXml
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A class that can be used to represent the dimenension of a <see cref="OfficeOpenXmlExcelWorkSheet"/>
    /// </summary>
    class ExcelWorkSheetDimension
    {

        const string worksheetSchema = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main";

        private string topLeft;
        private string bottomRight;
        private int firstRow;
        private int firstCol;
        private int lastRow;
        private int lastCol;

        private static String handleDimensionFromExcelWorksheet(ExcelWorkSheet w)
        {
            if (w == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("w");

            XmlNode n = w.WorksheetXml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//d:dimension", w.NameSpaceManager);
            XmlAttribute dimensionRef = n.Attributes["ref"];
            if ((dimensionRef != null) && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dimensionRef.Value)))
                return dimensionRef.Value;

            // no dimension available...?
            throw new XmlException("dimension attribute not found!");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a ExcelWorkSheetDimension
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="w">The <see cref="OfficeOpenXmlExcelWorkSheet"/> to create the dimension object for</param>
        public ExcelWorkSheetDimension(ExcelWorkSheet w)
            : this(handleDimensionFromExcelWorksheet(w))
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a ExcelWorkSheetDimension using a string with Cell Range representation like 'A1:B5'.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dimension">a string with Cell Range representation like 'A1:B5'</param>
        public ExcelWorkSheetDimension(String dimension)
        {
            String[] dimensions = dimension.Split(':');
            this.topLeft = dimensions[0];
            this.bottomRight = dimensions[1];
            if (!ExcelCell.IsValidCellAddress(topLeft) || (!ExcelCell.IsValidCellAddress(BottomRight)))
                throw new ArgumentException("No valid excel sheet dimension!");
            firstRow = ExcelCell.GetRowNumber(topLeft);
            firstCol = ExcelCell.GetColumnNumber(topLeft);
            lastCol = ExcelCell.GetColumnNumber(bottomRight);
            lastRow = ExcelCell.GetRowNumber(bottomRight);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a ExcelWorkSheetDimension using a Excel two cell representations.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="topLeft">a top left cell, like 'A1'</param>
        /// <param name="rightBottom">a right bottom cell, like 'B5'</param>
        public ExcelWorkSheetDimension(String topLeft, String rightBottom)
            :
            this(String.Format("{0}:{1}", topLeft, rightBottom))
        {
        }

        public string TopLeft { get { return topLeft; } }
        public string BottomRight { get { return bottomRight; } }
        public int FirstCol { get { return firstCol; } }
        public int FirstRow { get { return firstRow; } }
        public int LastCol { get { return lastCol; } }
        public int LastRow { get { return lastRow; } }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "ExcelPackage". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

1>C:\Users\rgouldooz1\Desktop\RIC-BE\RICBackend\Controllers\UsersController.cs(60,23,60,30): warning CS0108: 'UsersController.GetUser()' hides inherited member 'ApiHelpers.BaseController.GetUser()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

1>C:\Users\rgouldooz1\Desktop\RIC-BE\RICBackend\Helpers\ExcelWorkheetDimension.cs(24,65,24,79): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ExcelWorkSheet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
1>C:\Users\rgouldooz1\Desktop\RIC-BE\RICBackend\Helpers\ExcelWorkheetDimension.cs(42,40,42,54): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ExcelWorkSheet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: `ExcelWorkSheet ` is this your own class?

Comment: No it's not a class that I made. I believe the error has something to do with a missing package or assembly.

Comment: You can click on the `ExcelWorkSheet` on the code and press `Ctrl + .` on key board and see if it suggests any namespace of references to be added.

Comment: Yeah I've done that, and all it proposes is to generate class 'ExcelWorkSheet'. However that creates more errors.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally figured it out. I had to go and add the package manually by finding it in the project's package directory and adding ExcelPackage.dll

right-click on References on Solution Explorer -> Add References -> Browse for package and add .dll file.